# Iterating with Python

Tags: python, iteration

I have two arrays and from these two I have to create another one in this way:

```
  for i in arange(0,len(second_array),1):
     third_array[i] = my_function(first_array[i],second_array[i])
```

Here `my_function` is a procedure which takes two scalars as inputs and then return another scalar. My problem is that the arrays I usually work with are huge and so the above loops takes forever. Is there a way to avoid the loop but still filling the array `third_array` the way I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `map` seems to be marginally quicker than a list comprehension:

```
import cProfile, numpy as np
from operator import add

A = np.random.rand(1000000)
B = np.random.rand(1000000)

>>> cProfile.run('C = map(add, A, B)')
         3 function calls in 0.693 seconds

>>> cProfile.run('C = [a+b for a,b in izip(A,B)]')
         2 function calls in 0.765 seconds

>>> cProfile.run('for i in np.arange(0,len(B),1): C[i] = A[i]+B[i]')
         4 function calls in 1.971 seconds
```

But as @larsmans says, using a vectorized solution will be much quicker:

```
>>> cProfile.run('C = A + B')
         2 function calls in 0.005 seconds
```

Answer (score 4):

Since you're using `arange`, I take it you're using NumPy. Try to rewrite `my_function` so that it takes two arrays instead of two scalar values and use vectorized operations.

Answer (score 3):

How could you avoid looping if you need to access each element of both lists? I don't really understand your question.

But you can do it a bit more simply. In Python 3:

```
third_array = [my_function(a, b) for a, b in zip(first_array, second_array)]
```

In Python 2, it's better to use

```
from itertools import izip
third_array = [my_function(a, b) for a, b in izip(first_array, second_array)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're already using NumPy, it may be worth exploring [universal functions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) (`ufunc`) and [`numpy.frompyfunc()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frompyfunc.html#numpy.frompyfunc).

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: first_array = np.arange(10)

In [3]: second_array = np.arange(10, 20)

In [5]: def halfsum(a, b): return (a + b) / 2.0
   ...: 

In [7]: halfsum_ufunc = np.frompyfunc(halfsum, 2, 1)

In [8]: halfsum_ufunc(first_array, second_array)
Out[8]: array([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0, 9.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 13.0, 14.0], dtype=object)
```

One caveat is that `frompyfunc`-created ufuncs always return PyObject arrays. I am not sure if there's a way around that.